# Can it be shown that this expression is decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, products, discrete-optimization

Suppose $x$ and $k$ are both odd integers such that $1 < k \leq x$. Is it true that the expression,
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^{x \left( \frac{k-1}{2} \right)} \left( \frac{x + 2i - 1}{x + 2i - 2} \right)
\end{align*}
is decreasing in $x$ for any such $k$? Graphing this expression would suggest so, but I have had difficulty showing it to be true.

Answer (score 0):

For each term in the product:

$$\frac{x+2i-1}{x+2i-2} = 1+\frac{1}{x+2i-2}$$

Right side is decreasing in $x$, and finite product of decreasing functions is decreasing as well.

Comment: Thanks! Is this true even if the upper bound of the product is increasing in $x$?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to see if you take a first derivative of this product. All the terms will be negative, so their sum will be negative as well. If the product is infinite, then you need to prove it converges to something - that's why I've written *finite* product